# How Does AWS CloudFront Detect Mobile Devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront, user-agent

AWS CloudFront can detect the device type based on the value of the User-Agent header:

> If you want CloudFront to cache different versions of your objects
>   based on the device a user is using to view your content, configure
>   CloudFront to forward the applicable headers to your custom origin:
>
> - CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer
> - CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer
> - CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer
> - CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer
>
> Based on the value of the User-Agent header, CloudFront sets the value
>   of these headers to true or false before forwarding the request to
>   your origin. If a device falls into more than one category, more than
>   one value might be true. For example, for some tablet devices,
>   CloudFront might set both CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer and
>   CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer to true.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-device

I'm wondering if AWS has published a list of user agents they use to detect mobile browsers.

The documentation mentioned "If a device falls into more than one category", so I need to know how it determines these categories.

Comment: Observation: the only overlap I have ever seen in practice is the example from the documentation: `CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer` and `CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer` both set to `true`.  As a result, I always evaluate these in a specific order: SmartTV, Tablet, Mobile, Desktop...stopping with the first `true` value that I encounter and using this result to categorize the device.  Desktop seems to be always true if the other 3 are false, regardless of the UA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS uses detects the device base on the user agent, but doesn't provide any details.

A list of user agents can be found [here](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/mobile-browser-user-agent-strings).